# Change DNS TTL for every records in a zone

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, ttl

I have a forward lookup zone with a lot of A records.
If I change the TTL for the zone, it does not apply to records (they keep the previous TTL setting). I have to manually change the TTL for every records.

Is it the expected behaviour? How can I change every record's TTL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should update them if they are static entries after you restart DNS or reload the zone IF the entries don't have manual TTLs applied to them.

See here for a Technet thread that discusses the functionality and explains why the SOA TTL changes may or may not take affect for existing A records: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/031d48f5-46ae-4e6d-ae85-ae715e7c1206/ttl-of-dns-records-not-updated-when-soa-minimum-ttl-is-changed?forum=winserverNIS

However, if they are dynamic updates via either DHCP or DNS then the TTL defaults to 20 minutes.

> Whenever a dynamic update client registers in DNS, the associated A
>   and PTR resource records include the TTL, which by default is set to
>   20 minutes. You can change the default setting by modifying the
>   **DefaultRegistrationTTL** entry in the following registry subkey:
>
> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services \Tcpip\Parameters**
>
> The entry has a DWORD value and lists the TTL in seconds. A small
>   value causes cached entries to expire sooner, which increases DNS
>   traffic but decreases the risk of entries becoming stale. Expiring
>   entries quickly is useful for computers that frequently renew their
>   DHCP leases. A large value causes cached entries to be retained
>   longer, decreasing DNS traffic but increasing the risk of entries
>   becoming stale. Long retention times are useful for computers that
>   renew their DHCP leases infrequently.

But I wouldn't recommend changing the defaults for the dynamic updates.

Comment: In the link you provided, a guy says that the TTL defined at SOA level is applied to new records, not the old ones. I did not set an explicit TTL for my records, but they don't update, they keep the old TTL: so this guy explained my issue. I'll have to manually update every records... let's read dnscmd man page ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While this may (or may not) apply to the Windows world, you normally use the alias $TTL at the start of the zone file to specify the default expiration time of all resource records without their own TTL value.

For example:

```
$TTL 1h
example.com.  IN  SOA  ns.example.com. username.example.com. (
          2007120710 ; serial number of this zone file
          1d         ; slave refresh (1 day)
          2h         ; slave retry time in case of a problem (2 hours)
          4w         ; slave expiration time (4 weeks)
          1h         ; maximum caching time in case of failed lookups (1 hour)
          )
example.com.         NS    ns             ; ttl = 1h
mail          3w     A     192.0.0.1      ; ttl = 3w
```

Comment: Yes, that's the "normal" behaviour. I thought that it will apply to windows's DNS server, but it seems I was wrong.